# How can I check if a parameter/variable is a custom type?

Tags: php, variables, types, casting

for my new job I have to learn PHP, and so far I'm finding it quite frustrating (I'm used to desktop languages, like C#, Java, etc.).

I'm kind of teaching myself the language, and just creating little projects at a time.

Right now I have three classes:

```
Customer
DateOfBirth
Address
```

In the Customer class, I have getter and setter methods. For the setter methods, I'd like to check the type of a parameter.

For example: (pseudo):

```
func set_address($address)
    if $address typeof Addess then
        this->address = $address
    else then
        throw ArgumentException("Invalid parameter!");
    end
end
```

I hope you get what I mean. 
I just want things to be right and not get used to doing stupid things.

I hope you can help!
Cheers in advance!

Comment: You were close. Instead of `typeof` it's `instanceof` (BTW: I love your attempt with the pseudo code. Makes your question clear and shows what you want to know)

Comment: Another way to enforce type of an argument is to use type hinting in the signature: `public function set_address (Address $address) { ... }`

Comment: There is a goog example in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) hope this hepl ;)

Comment: @Rizier123 Might as well do my best and help others help me, right? :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved it like this:
    <code>if ($address instanceof Address) $this->$m_address = $address;</code>